# Why is a non-const rvalue move constructor called in this case?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, move-semantics

I have seen the related questions and they mostly talk about if we should have const rvalue references as a parameter or not. But I still fail to reason why a *non-const move constructor* is being called in the following code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class A 
    {
    public:
      A (int const &&i) { cout << "const rvalue constructor"; }
      A (int &&i) { cout << "non const rvalue constructor"; }
   };


   int const foo (void)
   {
     const int i = 3;
     return i;
   }

  int main (void)
  {
     A a(foo());
  }
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but returning a `const` value from a function is really quite meaningless. Nothing will stop the caller from storing the value in a non-const variable anyway.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, how can you get const rvalues then?

Comment: Just for kicks, [try your sample with a non-scalar type](https://ideone.com/0x2Hda). ttbomk a const prvalue for a scalar is fictitious.

Comment: @sanjivgupta Const "values" of what type? What do you mean? What is the use case?

Comment: @curiousguy, yes for aggregates it calls the const T&& version. Why the variance? is it not something covered by standard?

Comment: @sanjivgupta There is no such thing as a `const int` rvalue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a slightly modified version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>

#if 0
using T = int;
#else
struct T {T(int){}};
#endif

    using namespace std;
    class A {
      public:
      A (T const &&i) { cout << "const rvalue constructor"; }
      A (T &&i) { cout << "non const rvalue constructor"; }
   };


   T const
   foo (void)
   {
     const T i = 3;
     return i;
   }

  int main()
  {
    A a(foo());
  }
```

When `T == int`, you get the non-const overload.  When `T` is a class type, you get the const overload.  This behavior falls out of section 8.2.2 [expr.type]/p2:

> If a prvalue initially has the type “*cv* `T`”, where `T` is a cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of the expression is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis.

Translation:  The language doesn't have `const`-qualified scalar prvalues.  They simply don't exist.

Comment: Ah!! I thought one of the design goals of C++ was to make user-defined types behave as built-in types do.

Comment: Design goals are often conflicting.  Another design goal of C++ was to be compatible with C.

Comment: @sanjivgupta Being silly isn't a design goal. A scalar can just be copied. Moving from `int` is just pointless!

Comment: Oooh What an interesting tidbit!

Comment: @curiousguy, remembering different rules for scalar and aggregates is even more silly.

Comment: @sanjivgupta Copying a scalar is cheap; cheaper than stealing its value. So it's reasonable that a move from a scalar is a normal copy and doesn't change the source. And BTW, builtin operators are not overloaded operators. `1 + 1.` doesn't go through overloading resolution. Implicit conversions of scalars are unlike user defined conversions. Pointers conversions are unlike smart pointer conversion. Covariant return types work with pointers not classes. `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`... cannot be overloaded on classes. Etc.